Can I use simplicial homology mod 2 for topological data analysis?
I’ve started working on my masters project in TDA (topological data analysis) and I’m currently getting to grips with simplicial homology. I can’t seem to get a straight answer online, so I thought I’d ask here.
I’m relatively confident that I can work mod 2 and ignore orientations of simplicies in this context, as (as far as I can tell) orientation isn’t relevant in TDA. However, I’m not entirely sure, and I don’t want to commit to working in mod 2 to later find out it’s not sufficient. Some clarification would be appreciated!
P.S. I’ve currently been using Essential Topology by Martin D. Crossley which does an amazing job at explaining simplicial homology. If anybody has any book recommendations concerning TDA, that would be super helpful. Thanks!

Yes, working mod 2 is fine (and quite common).

To expand on my comment, working over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is quite common. A good reference is the book "Persistence Theory: From Quiver Representations to Data Analysis" by Steve Oudot, which has multiple examples/explanations mod 2.
In general, you're safe working over any finite field, and this is what most software does. With infinite fields like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ you are also fine, although some technical results require the field to algebraically closed. When working with rings that aren't fields, you get into a lot of problems.
It's wrong to say that orientation doesn't matter in TDA, it's just that if you work mod 2 it disappears. Your choice of coefficients is related to your intuition/bias as to what kind of homology you want to see/find. A cool example here is the topological type of small image patches in natural images, which is a Klein bottle. It is hard to see this directly with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients, because with such coefficients a torus and a Klein bottle have the same Betti numbers, but it can be verified by working in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.
